# How to scale controls with maintained aspect ratio and position without viewbox?

Tags: .net, wpf, canvas, scale, viewbox

I am trying to replicate the display *rearranger UI* in **display settings**, in which there are button placed with respect to their physical location and can be rearranged with mouse-drag

[image: Windows 10 display rearrangement]

I can get the screen bounds from the screen class

> System.Windows.Forms.Screen

and create button with the specified bounds in a canvas, but they are too large (i.e. 1366 x 768) to be shown in a container, so I decided to use WPF's inbuilt **ViewBox** control

The problem with viewbox is it scales not only the bounds but also the rendered element

[image]

I can't control the **BorderThickness**, **FontSize** and **Margin**, they become extremely negligible to notice or too big when the canvas size is changed.

What I need is Scale just the size, but not everything. I want the borderthickness to have a fixed size, not scaled. In the settings one the BorderThickness of the buttons stay the same even after resizing. What ever I try I get this >

[image]

Here the Button's size is 1366 x 768, its borderthickness is 1 px (not clearly visible, I have to set it 4 px to make it clear), and have a font size of 240 px.

This Button is hosted within a canvas whose size is programmaticaly determined, the canvas is hosted in a viewbox which is hosted in a border. What should I do to just scale the size?

Comment: Why don't you create the Buttons with a fixed fraction of the actual screen dimension, e.g. a 137 x 77 Button for a 1366 x 768 screen?

Comment: I can do that but when there are more than 2 screen, it should scale itself down instead of overflowing. (I don't want scrollbar appearing there) I want them to be placed according to their location, if I scale them down by factor (eg. 10) I also need to scale their position. I don't know how to find a fixed factor to scale them down :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally achieved it, I got rid of the viewbox and managed to do it through code

The Code :

```vb
    Private Sub LoadScreens()
        Dim ox As Integer = 0
        Dim oy As Integer = 0
        Dim canvaswidth As Integer = 0
        Dim canvasheight As Integer = 0
        Dim rect As New List(Of System.Drawing.Rectangle)
        For i = 0 To Forms.Screen.AllScreens.Count - 1
            Dim screen = Forms.Screen.AllScreens(i)
            Dim r = screen.Bounds
            rect.Add(r)
        Next
        For Each r In rect
            If r.X < ox Then ox = r.X
            If r.Y < oy Then oy = r.Y
        Next
        For Each r In rect
            If r.X + r.Width + Math.Abs(ox) > canvaswidth Then canvaswidth = r.X + r.Width + Math.Abs(ox)
            If r.Y + r.Height + Math.Abs(oy) > canvasheight Then canvasheight = r.Y + r.Height + Math.Abs(oy)
        Next

        ScreenCanvas.Children.Clear()

        Dim scale = GetScale(TParent.ActualWidth, TParent.ActualHeight, canvaswidth, canvasheight)

        ScreenCanvas.Width = canvaswidth * scale
        ScreenCanvas.Height = canvasheight * scale

        For i = 0 To rect.Count - 1
            Dim r = rect(i)
            Dim left = (r.X - ox) * scale
            Dim top = (r.Y - oy) * scale
            Dim nr As New Primitives.ToggleButton With {
                .Width = r.Width * scale,
                .Height = r.Height * scale,
                .Content = New TextBlock() With {.Text = i + 1, .VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center, .HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center}
            }
            ScreenCanvas.Children.Add(nr)
            Canvas.SetLeft(nr, left)
            Canvas.SetTop(nr, top)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Function GetScale(w1 As Double, h1 As Double, w2 As Double, h2 As Double) As Double
        Dim scaleHeight = h1 / h2
        Dim scaleWidth = w1 / w2
        Dim scale = Math.Min(scaleHeight, scaleWidth)
        Return scale
    End Function
```

The ToggleButtons are programmaticaly created, scaled, positioned and are added to the scaled canvas : **ScreenCanvas** which is hosted in a grid **TParent**.

The XAML :

```xml
          <Border CornerRadius="10" Margin="40" Padding="40" Background="#22aaaaaa">
            <Grid x:Name="TParent" Height="150" >
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                    <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2">
                                        <ContentPresenter TextBlock.Foreground="Black"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </Grid.Resources>
                <Canvas x:Name="ScreenCanvas" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
```

Here's the final result :

[image]

Now I can control the borderthickness, cornerradius, margin :)

Edit :

I have updated the UI and added code to update their location and size when the grid size is changed.

Code :

```vb
     Private Sub TParent_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As SizeChangedEventArgs) Handles TParent.SizeChanged
        If e.WidthChanged AndAlso _init Then
            Dim canvaswidth = ScreenCanvas.ActualWidth
            Dim canvasheight = ScreenCanvas.ActualHeight
            Dim scale = GetScale(TParent.ActualWidth, TParent.ActualHeight, canvaswidth, canvasheight)
            ScreenCanvas.Width = canvaswidth * scale
            ScreenCanvas.Height = canvasheight * scale
            For Each c As FrameworkElement In ScreenCanvas.Children
                c.Width = c.ActualWidth * scale
                c.Height = c.ActualHeight * scale
                Dim top = Canvas.GetTop(c) * scale
                Dim left = Canvas.GetLeft(c) * scale
                Canvas.SetTop(c, top)
                Canvas.SetLeft(c, left)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

UI :

[image]